# Deploying django on app engine 500 server error

Tags: django, google-app-engine-python, app.yaml

I am trying to deploy completed web-app (runs locally) on the app engine. The app has no databases and the web page is static. My primary problem is that I try to deploy the app and I get a server error. I suspect that the issue lies with my app.yaml file but I cannot seem to fix it. Here is my yml file:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: personal/static/

- url: /.*
  script: mysite.wsgi.application
```

The directory is organized so that the 'personal' is an installed app and static, templates etc. are inside the personal folder.

Answer (score 0):

In settings file, make DEBUG=False for short time to just check what is error, then return it back to True